# My SharePoint Content Type does not appear

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, contenttype

I have a little problem here.
I'm working on a sharePoint solution which contains some content types. 
To deploy my solution on the Web Application, i use a handmade powershell script.

The solution deploys correctly. The problem is that the content type does not appear when i search them with powershell, but they appear in the site collection's content type menu.

The only way i found to make them appear with powershell is to restart the server. 
Have anyone already been through that problem?

Comment: Try to restart the powershell. Restarting the application pool has no effect on the app domain of the currently running powershell.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer, 
I've just tried it manually. Can you give me a clue how to restart the SP Management Shell using Powershell please ? 
Thanks

Comment: What you can do is split the script in two parts: First part deploy the solution; second part management/actions (?) on the content types. You could run the second part with `powershell.exe -file/-command` switch. I've never done this before, so I don't know if this works...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it works like that :).
I forgot to add the Add-PSSnapin Command, so i had troubles at the beginning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the list already had its schemaxml. To modify this schemaxml with a new one, i had to create a new list

Answer (score -1):

Try recycling the application pool for the webapplication you are deploying to instead of restarting the server.

This is a standard part of deployment, so your powershell script should be modified to do this.

Comment: Hey
I've just tried it with this :

$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonation Impersonate -ComputerName "win-sharepoint" -namespace "root/MicrosoftIISv2" -class IISApplicationPool|Where-Object{$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/AppPools/SharePoint - 9090"}
$wmi.Recycle();

But it still doesn't appear. 
Is there more steps to do ? Sorry if it's a silly question, but i've just began to learn SharePoint 1 month ago